# How to compute the area between two graphs?

Tags: time-series, algorithms

[image]

In the chart above, how can I derive the area between the two graphs, taking into consideration positive and negative areas?

[image]

Comment: Are these curves stochastic or deterministic? Can you evaluate these curves over the entire interval, or only at the dots?

Comment: Hi, Lews: There are some options here that ought to be spelled out. Because the x-axis is logarithmic, do you want the area as shown or the area as plotted against $M$ itself? Should the area be computed from the apparent data or based on the fitted curves? Because the curves appear to be fits to data and the data show spreads, do you need to come up with a standard error of the estimated area? I wonder, too, whether you really want the area between these two curves or whether you're looking for something else: what would this area *mean* for your study? How do you intend to interpret it?

Comment: Hey guys, I am not sure what you mean but I would try to explain.
What I would like is to get the area between two timeseries. Regardless of it being a linear or log axis. So if the two timeseries overlap completely then the area should be 0 or close 0. Is there some formula I can try?

Comment: Lews, first of all, there are no time series in evidence here: your graphic only shows plots of %Relaxation against the logarithm of Acetylcholine. The apparent area is around 1 and its units of measurement are %Relaxation *times* log concentration (a strange unit indeed!). Equivalent plots of %Relaxation against the Acetylcholine concentration itself would be separated by an area of about $10^{-5}$; this area would be expressed in units of %Relaxation *times* concentration. This area would *not* be the logarithm of the first area! What is the reason you need the area, by the way?

Comment: @whuber hopefully that's a better graph. The area is supposed to show by how much the graph differs from the other

Comment: What specific statistical problem are you trying to solve, Lews?

Comment: I inlined both your images, but I'm not sure how the second one relates to the problem or if it was pasted in by mistake.

Comment: Thanks @Anna.  Lews, it sounds like you're interested primarily in the computational aspects and not in the stats. Ordinarily we would migrate the question to our [programming site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but I think they would close it because it's too vague. Consider posting a new version over there and explain what kind of input you have, what kind of output you want, and why you're trying to accomplish this: then it's likely you'll get a good and timely answer.